# Uploading files in .net with WebClient (and silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, file-upload, webclient

I have the code below which I am using to upload files to my ashx page. It works great, although I cant seem to find a proper way of getting how much it has transferred.

The calling code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenWriteCompleted += (s2, e2) =>
{
   PushData(e2.Result, offset);
   e2.Result.Close();
};
wc.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
```

The push data code:

```
private void PushData(Stream output, long offset)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    bytesRead = theFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead != 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        totalBytesDone += bytesRead;
        FireUpdateEvent(bytesRead);
    }
}
```

The above code is slightly different to my actual code, for brevity sake.
Now, I had presumed that when it gets to `output.Write(buffer,0,bytesRead);` that that was the point where it sent the actual data and it would lock up and only goto the next line once its finished writing that section. But it goes on to `totalBytesDone += bytesRead;` before its written anything to the server. I presume the reason is that its doing the writing in a separate thread in the background (or I'm actually looking at the wrong section of code and it writes somewhere else) - but for my `totalBytesDone` code to work I **want** it to lock up until its finished sending (I can put this all in a seperate thread later).

I've downloaded tons of examples for doing this and they either dont work properly with my ashx file handler (I cant change it) or they use a WebClient method that just reports on 50% progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140195/webclient-asyncupload-progress-percentage-always-returns-50/2141036#2141036).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately Silverlight doesn't support the full range of methods.

Comment: Well then you will have to resort to HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse.

Comment: And how does one know what is and what is not supported in SilverLight version of c#?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, what kind of response is this?.. :| And actually I'm reading documentation and I do not see currently if anything is not supported in SilveLight implementation.

Comment: @Matt, what did you mean exactly when you said that SilveLight doesn't support full range of methods?

Comment: @jayarjo, well then I guess you are not reading carefully. Here's an example with the `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` method: http://i.imgur.com/0ffxI.png. As you can see this method is supported in Silverlight, otherwise it wouldn't have appeared in the list. And here's the [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx) method (the synchronous version) which is not supported because in Silverlight you can do only asynchronous HTTP requests. That's what Matt meant with Silverlight not supporting the full range of methods/classes.

Comment: Now that was completely not obvious :( thanks, for the tip though... so UploadFile and UploadFileAsync are not available in SilverLight... that kinda sucks.

Comment: Interesting... I only yesterday read about WebClient.DownloadString in SilverLight, here: http://wildermuth.com/2008/9/27/WebClient_vs_WebRequest_in_Silverlight_2. The whole thing is now even more confusing...

Comment: No, Silverlight doesn't support the `DownloadString` method. It supports only the `DownloadStringAsync` method as shown in the code samples of the blog post you read. All network communication must be asynchronous in Silverlight.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, actually I just realized why it was so confusing in fact - I'm currently reading a book about SilverLight and C# and here is the page that uses UploadFileAsync in SilverLight to upload a file: http://books.google.ge/books?id=PJmgeIdZT3YC&lpg=PR26&ots=VtO5mjhnte&dq=Pro%20Silverlight%204%20in%20C%23&pg=PA849#v=onepage&q=Pro%20Silverlight%204%20in%20C%23&f=false... According to your tip it shouldn't be possible... ???

Comment: No, I grasp it, that's not a problem. The problem is that when I click a dropdown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144232.aspx there's no SilveLight in the list...

Comment: OK, you are right. This method is not available in Silverlight. You could use the OpenWriteAsync method instead.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, do you say that the book that I referenced above (it's about SilverLight) is all wrong?.. :| I need to try myself I guess.