# WebClient.UploadValuesAsync not updating progress properly

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar, webclient

I have a WebClient which I use to upload a file in the following way, base64Encoded is a picture encoded as a base64 string as that is what the imgur server expects:

```
    public Upload()
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_UploadProgressChanged);
        webClient.UploadValuesCompleted += new UploadValuesCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadValuesCompleted);    

        NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
        values.Add("key", "imgur api key");
        values.Add("image", base64Encoded);
        webClient.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri("http://api.imgur.com/2/upload"), "POST", values);        
    }
```

This is the event handler for the UploadProgressChanged:

```
    private void webClient_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int percentage = e.ProgressPercentage * 2;

        progressBar.Value = percentage;
        percentageTextBlock.Text = (percentage).ToString() + "%";
    }
```

Now my problem is that the event handler is only called once right at the start, reports a `ProgressPercentage` of 50 and is then not being called anymore. The file uploads successfully, but my progressbar is not working. This is not because I'm uploading a small file as I've also tried this with files of several mb which also report a `ProgressPercentage` of 50 right away. `e.BytesSent` is no help either because that one is equal to `e.TotalBytesToSend` right away as well. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [bug with this event](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/470465/async-ftp-upload-with-webclient-never-completes#details) which was fixed in .NET 4.0. And here's a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140195/webclient-asyncupload-progress-percentage-always-returns-50).

Comment: I see. I changed my project to target .NET 4.0 instead of 3.5 and it works perfectly well indeed. However, I don't want to use .NET 4.0 yet because most of my users will still be using .NET 3.5 and wouldn't want to install 4.0 just for my app. Is there any workaround possible? Should I use the UploadValues() method on a different thread and then update the GUI myself?

Comment: @dimski, you will need to implement the progress yourself by writing directly to the request stream in chunks. I am afraid you cannot use `UploadValuesAsync` even if it is a very convenient method. So you could use the `OpenWriteAsync` method and write directly to the request stream in chunks and calling some custom event to report progress.