# File upload from WP7 with form fields

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, file-upload

I've seen a few examples on file upload from WP7 - there a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141036/109102) to upload a file.  But in my case I'm sending the file to a 3rd party who expects from form fields with the POST.  I haven't seen any examples of this yet.

There's a codeproject article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72232/Csharp-File-Upload-with-form-fields-cookies-and-he.aspx), that explains how to do it in non-silverlight friendly code.

I could port over the codeproject article - or does this already exist somewhere?

Comment: Search "mutlipart form" to find resources on the subject. I think that's what you're searching for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622900/wp7-post-form-with-an-image

Comment: that's exactly what I'm after - thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search "mutlipart form" to find resources on the subject. I think that's what you're searching for: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5622900/wp7-post-form-with-an-image